# "in" operator fails even in a defined interval

Tags: delphi, operators

I have a weird problem and I don't know where I am doing wrong.

I have the following code. Please look at the end of it that's where it fails I commented it:

```
var
  IDH:PImageDosHeader;
  INH:PImageNtHeaders;
  ISH:PImageSectionHeader;
  buf:Pointer;
  FS:TFileStream;
  ep,tmp1,tmp2:DWORD;
  i:Word;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        FS:=TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
        GetMem(buf,FS.size);
        FS.Read(buf^,FS.Size);
        FS.Free;
        IDH:=PImageDosHeader(buf);
        INH:=PImageNtHeaders(DWORD(buf) + DWORD(IDH^._lfanew));
        ep:=INH^.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        for i:=0 to INH^.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
        begin
          ISH:=PimageSectionHeader(DWORD(INH) + sizeof(TImageNtHeaders) + i * sizeof(TImageSectionHeader));
          tmp1:=ISH^.VirtualAddress;
          tmp2:=ISH^.VirtualAddress + ISH^.Misc.VirtualSize;
          ShowMessageFmt('%d -> %d .. %d',[ep,tmp1,tmp2]);
          if ep in [tmp1..tmp2] then ShowMessage('Got it'); //This fails even if ep is in the defined interval. Why?
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Of course I can replace that line with

```
if (ep>=tmp1) and (ep<=tmp2)
```

but I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A set is a collection of values of the same type. This type must be ordinal, and a variable of this type must have at most 256 possible values. ([Official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Structured_Types#Sets)) Hence, a set cannot contain integers, since there are more than 256 possible integers.

You could use the `InRange` function:

```
if InRange(ep, tmp1, tmp2) then
```

(`uses Math`).

Comment: @opc0de: FWIW, I really think the compiler should say something about this. At the very least, it should give a warning...

Comment: Maybe in the future versions :))

Comment: @opc0de: not in future versions. I guess current versions will also warn or refuse to compile.

Comment: @Rudy run the code i posted if you see a warning or an error i owe you a beer ;) if not you owe me a six pack ;)

Comment: @opc0de: I don't bet, but I can only test it at home. No Delphi here, in my clinic. So be patient...

Comment: @opc0de: I tested it and it didn't cause a warning, nor did it function. Looks like a bug.